# Rspec: Getting Omniauth/oauth0 working with a Faraday Request

Tags: rspec, graphql, faraday, faraday-oauth

I am trying to test a graphql request with Faraday, but I first need to authenticate with omniauth/auth0.

I got it to authenticate by setting

```
   def sign_in(user, invalid=false, strategy = :auth0)
      invalid ?  mock_invalid_auth_hash : mock_valid_auth_hash(user)
      Rails.application.env_config["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[strategy.to_sym]
      visit "/auth/#{strategy.to_s}/callback"
   end
```

But when graphql gets tested it totally loses that cookie since this is a brand new request:

```
require 'graphlient'

RSpec.shared_context "GraphQL Client", shared_context: :metadata do
  let(:client) do
    Graphlient::Client.new('https://www.example.org/graphql') do |client|
      client.http do |h|
        h.connection do |c|
          c.use Faraday::Adapter::Rack, app
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How can I set the environment via Faraday to be authenticated before it connects to GraphQL? Or is there a better way to test GraphQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out by not using graphlient and faraday (though I didn't try it once I figured out what was wrong, so it may still work, but here's an alternative).

Changed the `sign_in` method to a get request instead of visit:

#### spec/support/features/session_helpers.rb

```
def sign_in(user, invalid=false, strategy = :auth0)
  invalid ?  mock_invalid_auth_hash : mock_valid_auth_hash(user)
  get "/auth/#{strategy.to_s}"
  Rails.application.env_config["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[strategy.to_sym]
  get "/auth/#{strategy.to_s}/callback"
end
```

And in my rspec request test I did like so (I'll include a whole test example in case it helps anyone):

#### spec/support/graphql/client.rb

```
RSpec.shared_context "GraphQL Client", shared_context: :metadata do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  let(:post_query_as_user) do
    sign_in(user)
    params = { query: query }
    post "/graphql", params: params
  end

  def data
    JSON.parse(response.body)["data"]
  end
end
```

#### spec/graphql/queries/current_user_queries_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'GraphQL::Queries::CurrentUser', type: 'request' do
  include_context 'GraphQL Client'
  let(:query) do
    <<-GRAPHQL
      {
        current_user {
          id
          first_name
        }
      }
    GRAPHQL
  end

  it 'returns the current user with all user attributes' do
    post_query_as_user
    current_user = data["current_user"]
    expect(current_user["first_name"]).to eq(user.first_name)
  end
end
```